# Cant add import into Java class in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have several simple classes in Java IntelliJ code, however soon as I finish adding any import statement that statement disappears. It let me type statement `import java.util.*` , but when I complete writing statement with `;` in that moment whole statement disappears, with no error displayed.

Comment: IIRC there's a config for "automatically organize imports" or something like that. If an import isn't actually *used* it might be removed. Actually use a class from the import and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Optimize imports on the fly` is enabled. IDEA finds an unnecessary import and removes it. So you should deselect it if you want to disable this behavior. However, I recommend not to organize imports manually. Just write your code and IDEA will import everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Wild Card Imports `import com.package.*` is generally considered bad practice when writing Java as it clutters the local namespace that you're developing with. In this case,

> Intellij recommends wildcard imports if you're using more than 5 classes from the same package in your current namespace, however that can be disabled too.

Source: [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#disable-wildcard-imports)

Comment: While it's often considered "bad practice" I'm not sure what "cluttering the local namespace" means. Also it's best to include information from links rather than just posting a link.

Comment: @DaveNewton the said imported package classes might interfere(or conflict) other package (maybe, a 3rd party lib or an internal module that is under active development) classes that you have interfaced with, in that case every time you want to resolve the class from the current package, one'll have to specify the fully qualified class name like `com.package.child.ClassRequired` rather than just specifying `ClassRequired`. There's nothing wrong with using wildcards, it's just that it keeps from maintaining a conflict/future safe code base.

Comment: That’s certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

All import statements were disappearing. In Setting>Editor>General>Auto Import I disabled  Optimize imports on the fly option and import statements dont disappear anymore.

Answer (score -3):

For the newer versions of Intellij, press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + s to open project settings, then choose Modules, under Dependencies tab choose the green + and add the folder in which your . class file is located. See if that helps

Comment: `java.util.*` is a standard Java import; there's no need to check for its class file location.